# How to make my app hide/disappear in the share list of another specific app or Phone Default sharing list?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to disappear/hide my application name from other application or phone default sharing list.

Any help would be appreciated[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually opposite. It shows on that list because your app's activities listed in Manifest file contain `<intent-filter>` entries that match criteria for data someone wants to share (that's why you may not see your app for one type of shared data but see it listed for other). If you do not want to be listed, remove these intent filters from your manifest file and you should be good.

See this docs: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

Comment: On which activity i can remove <intent-filter> ?

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to be able to handle share action for specific apps and filter unwanted apps from seeing your app in their share menu, then this is not doable.

As stated by [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive) you can only filter via data mime type that your app can handle